# How do I open a file with any other extension like .app from a exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, exe

Hi I am working on a Programming Language.
I completed all code I should just convert it into .exe file but how can I open any other extension (Like:PL.app).
Can anyone help.

Thank you

-Levers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrote python code in a file called foobar.py, then you can run your code simply by calling

```
python foobar.py
```

at the prompt (linux/bash or windows/cmd). There is no need to convert it into an exe just for running it.

There are few scenarios where you might want to make an exe out of your python code (that's a somewhat advanced usage), for that you can use something like [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) or other tools described in the [Hitchhiker's Guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/).

Comment: Got it but I already have a .exe file I should only open .app file using that .exe file or application